# How to call ambiguous method of extension on swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-extensions

//-- Module1

```
import Foundation

public extension String {
    public func testMethod() {
        print("something Module1 ---------------------")
    }
}
```

//-- Module2

```
import Foundation

public extension String {
    public func testMethod() {
        print("something Module2 ---------------------")
    }
}
```

//-- Code

```
import UIKit
import Module1
import Module2

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        "Hello".testMethod() //----- here is the problem, not any way to call it
        return true
    }
}
```

Is there any way to call ambiguous method `testMethod` to select from Module1 or Module2. Like `"Hello".(Module1.testMethod)()` or `"Hello".(Module2.testMethod())`

Comment: I haven't tested it myself, but according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534371/same-class-extension-in-two-different-modules, you can't.

Comment: Are that 3rd party modules which you cannot change? In that case you probably have to write a wrapper method in a separate source file which imports only one of the modules.

Comment: @MartinR Assume that both are the third party module I cannot modify either of them.

Comment: Have you tried e.g.
Module1.String.testMethod("hello")()

Comment: @RichardBirkett Don't u think testMethod is instance method of String extension. How can we call it like class method

Comment: @JackSparrow this is a common feature of Swift. If method(var: Type1) -> Type2 is an instance method of SomeClass, then method(obj: SomeClass) -> (Type1) -> Type2 is a class function of SomeClass. It means all functions are also variables even instance methods which need to know the object first.
In short SomeClass.method(myObject) is the same as myObject.method, giving you function-variables both of which you can then execute by putting the appropriate parentheses on the end.
Did you try my suggestion from before?

Comment: @RichardBirkett would u show me the exact syntax for this. I got error `Module1 has no member names 'String'` for the code `Module1.String.testMethod("Hello")()`

Comment: @JackSparrow I can't say I've actually tried it I'm afraid, I just assumed you knew how to refer to a class in a module (not sure why sorry). If you can't refer to a particular module there will be no way around this. It is just up to the developer to avoid clashes.