# why multiple optionals(wrap nil) compare with operator "==" return false?

Tags: swift

```
var opt1: Int??? = nil
var opt2: Int?? = nil
print(opt1 == opt2) // why is false?
```

At first I thought it was because of the **different types(Int??? and Int??)**, so I custom a operator `<==>` and use the same code as the `Optional' ==` source code to implement it:

```
extension Optional {
    public static func <==> (lhs: Wrapped?, rhs: Wrapped?) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case let (l?, r?):
            return l <==> r
        case (nil, nil): //I think it should match here
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
print(opt1 <==> opt2) // false
```

(the source code link: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift)

I saw from the breakpoint that lhs and rhs become the same type.

[image]

In other words, this is not caused by the type.

And `Optional' ~=` operator implementation in the source code:

```
public static func ~=(lhs: _OptionalNilComparisonType, rhs: Wrapped?) -> Bool {
    switch rhs {
    case .some:
      return false
    case .none:
      return true
    }
  }
```

According to the code above，I think `case (nil, nil):` in `static func <==>` should match, so `print(opt1 == opt2) and print(opt1 <==> opt2)`  should be `true`, but why it's `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four kinds of values that a `Int???` can have:

1. `.none` (`nil`)
2. `.some(.none)` (a non nil `Int???` wrapping a nil `Int??`)
3. `.some(.some(.none))` (a non nil `Int???` wrapping a non nil `Int??` wrapping a nil `Int?`)
4. `.some(.some(.some(n)))` where `n` is an `Int` (an `Int` wrapped by 3 layers of `Optional`s)

Similarly, there are three kinds of values that an `Int??` can have

1. `.none`
2. `.some(.none)`
3. `.some(.some(n))` where `n` is an `Int`

When you write `nil`, it always means `.none` of whatever type that context needs, so both `opt1` and `opt2` are `.none` here.

What happens when you pass them to the `==` operator? Well, After some overload resolution/type inference, the compiler finds that `==` takes a two `Int???` parameters, but you have passed an `Int??` as the second argument. Luckily, there exists a conversion from any value `t` of type `T` to type `T?` - `.some(t)`.

So after being passed into the `==`, `opt2` changes from `.none` to `.some(.none)`, as you can see from this code snippet:

```
func test(lhs: Int???, rhs: Int???) {
    if case .none = lhs, case .some(.none) = rhs {
        print("lhs is .none and rhs is .some(.none)")
    }
}

test(lhs: opt1, rhs: opt2) // prints
```

Hence they are "not equal".

The debugger seems to be showing both `.none` and `.some(.none)` as "nil", possibly because both of their `debugDescription`/`description` is "nil".

---

If you don't care about the multiple layers of optionals, you can just unwrap them to a single layer by doing `as? Int`, then compare:

```
print((opt1 as? Int) == (opt2 as? Int)) // true
```

Comment: Thanks. And I have another question, I extension Optional in my own swift file like this: `extension Optional where Wrapped: Equatable` and wrote  three `==` operator static func with the same signature as standard library,  I thought it should fail to compile: **Invalid redeclaration of '=='**. But it succeeded!  Why can it be override successfully？ The same method signature is override instead of overloaded, according to the documentation, the existing method cannot be overwritten

Comment: Is it because of **access control** ？

Comment: @Joiner [I had this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46123963/5133585). It’s apparently because `Optional` is in another module.

Comment: you saved me, thanks