# Swift Extension: augment existing class with method overloading

Tags: swift, logging, overloading, oslog

Consider the `Logger` class from the `OSLog` framework: [Logger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logger)

Since the OSLog API doesn't allow querying for the information such as the name of the file, the line and the function where the log commands have been invoked, I'd like to "embed" those values into the log entry itself.

This can be easily accomplished by adding a new method to the `Logger`:

```
extension Logger {
func d_debug(_ message: @autoclosure () -> Any, _ file: String = #file, _ function: String = #function, line: Int = #line, context: Any? = nil) {
    let converted = (file as NSString).lastPathComponent + ":" + String(line) + ":" + function + ": " + "\(message())"
    debug("\(converted)")
}
```

}

The problem with this approach is that I'll have to use the `d_debug` method instead of the standard `debug` method used by default. Therefore, this modified method will "leak" the implementation details outside of the extension.

What I'm looking for is an option to leverage method overloading and use a different type, i.e. a `String` as an input parameter so that my method will be preferred and not the original log method of the `Logger`.

For example, the original signature looks like this:

```
    ///
    /// - Warning: Do not explicity create OSLogMessage. Instead pass a string interpolation.
    ///
    /// - Parameter message: A string interpolation.
    public func debug(_ message: OSLogMessage)
```

However, I'd like to have a method like this:

```
func debug(_ message: @autoclosure () -> String, _ file: String = #file, _ function: String = #function, line: Int = #line) {
```

and to keep the notion that this method even exists completely hidden from the call site (if possible).

Ideally, if I remove the extension, the code should still complile.

Are there any options of achieving this behavior? Or anything like this would involve dynamic patching at runtime?

Comment: "and to keep the notion that this method even exists completely hidden from the call site" What does that mean? If the call site doesn't know about the method, how can it possibly call the method at all?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify a bit more, of course the call site will know about the method. But the idea I'm looking to implement is that the code will look identical. However, due to the type passed, is it possible to somehow unambiguously call my method? So far I've been only able to get compilation errors, which are expected since the signatures are the same/similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just name your method `debug`, and use the [`log(level:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logger/3551622-log) method to avoid infinite recursion.

```
log(level: .debug, "\(custom)")
```

Swift will resolve `debug(...)` calls to your own method instead of the built-in one, [as long as you are in the same module as the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46123963/5133585).

Also consider using the custom string interpolation provided by `OSLogMessage`.

```
func debug(_ message: @autoclosure () -> String, _ file: String = #file, _ function: String = #function, line: Int = #line) {
    log(level: .debug, "\((file as NSString).lastPathComponent):\(line):\(function):\(message())")
}
```

Either way though, the caller cannot make use of the custom string interpolation provided by `OSLogMessage`, such as custom formats, alignments and privacy. I don't think there is a way to implement that.

Comment: Either way though, the caller cannot make use of the custom string interpolation provided by OSLogMessage, such as custom formats, alignments and privacy -> this is not needed

Comment: Very interested concept, thank you so much. I'll take a look and get back if this actually resolves the problem I'm looking for.

Comment: This is the solution I've been looking for, works exactly as needed, i.e. transparently overrides the default behavior when the file is present in the target. The key was to call a parametrized method of the logger (i.e. with the `debug` / `info` etc level parameter) so that there is no chance of recursion.

Answer (score 1):

If two functions have different parameters, even though they have the same name, they are two different functions. i.e you can still do this with extension

```
extension Logger { 

internal func debug(_ message: @autoclosure () -> String, _ file: String = #file, _ function: String = #function, line: Int = #line) {
    let converted = (file as NSString).lastPathComponent + ":" + String(line) + ":" + function + ": " + "\(message())"
    debug("\(converted)") 
}
```

==EDIT==

I did not realize that all your extra parameters have default values.  In this case you can still distinguish function call like below

```
extension Logger { 

internal func debug(_ message: @autoclosure () -> String, _ file: String = #file, _ function: String = #function, line: Int = #line) {
    let converted = (file as NSString).lastPathComponent + ":" + String(line) + ":" + function + ": " + "\(message())"
    self.debug(_:)("\(converted)") 
}
```

But I am not sure if having an [ambuiguity over function signatures](https://forums.swift.org/t/ambiguity-when-a-method-signature-with-a-default-value-parameter-matches-another-method-signature/38314/7) is a good idea at all.

Comment: In this case, I'll get a warning/error due to the potential recursion. In practice, a recursion happens and the app is terminated due to consuming all available memory.